# SQL Display a row value based on a comparison using a Union

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table with a column labeled state. I want to select all the rows (and columns) from that table and display their information. However, I want the state column to display "CA" if they are from California and "Not from CA" if they are from anywhere else. What is the command to swap a value.

Here is what I have so far, I just need the swap command. Not even sure what to search for on Google for this so I'm hoping to find the answer here.

```
SELECT VendorName, VendorState
FROM Vendors
WHERE VendorState='CA'
UNION
SELECT VendorName, VendorState
FROM Vendors
WHERE VendorState<>'CA'
ORDER BY VendorName
```

I came to the specific answer I wanted by SQLMenaces query format so he gets his answer accepted. But this is what I wanted for anyone else who might stumble on this question.

```
SELECT VendorName, VendorState
FROM Vendors
WHERE VendorState='CA'
UNION
SELECT VendorName, 'Outside CA'
FROM Vendors
WHERE VendorState<>'CA'
ORDER BY VendorName
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
SELECT VendorName, 
CASE VendorState WHEN 'CA' 
THEN 'CA' ELSE 'Not from CA' END VendorState
FROM Vendors
```

and just to show you how you would swap in your query, you can do

```
SELECT 'Whatever here' as VendorState
FROM Vendors
```